# Select Between two dates missing the last day

Tags: php, mysql, select, between

i am selecting some data from mysql with between, and i am missing the last day i think.

My Sample Data is:

```
2012-11-30 18:23:20,  
2012-11-30 18:24:54,  
2012-11-30 18:28:03,  
2012-12-01 11:50:36,  
2012-12-07 00:22:44
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN  '2012-11-30' AND  '2012-12-07'
```

Result is all my Sample Data but the **2012-12-07** date is missing. Can anybody explain how i can feth it too? Is there any other way than adding +1 to the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` 
WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN  '2012-11-30 00:00:00' AND  '2012-12-07 23:59:59'
```

so that you can catch all records with your start date and end date.